# Get Result set from two date range in the date(d-M-Y) format

Tags: php, mysql, date

In my database the dates are saved in the format are as follows -------

```
Col_date

05-May-2014

07-APR-2014
```

In my dashboard I have to show the result from my table which col_date are between the current date and the date before 7days from the current date.

I get the current date  ------

```
$curdate = date('d-M-Y', time());
```

I get the 7 days back date -------

```
$backdate = date('d-M-Y', time());
$date1 = strtotime($backdate);
$date = strtotime("-7 day", $date1);
$prevdate = date('d-M-Y', $date);
```

I run the query ----------

```
select * from `requisition` WHERE col_date >= '$prevdate' AND col_date <= '$curdate'  order by `rq_no` DESC
```

**but my problem is when it search and show the result it can't compare the Month. Suppose $curdate is '05-May-2014' and $prevdate is '02-May-2014' then it show the results between this dates also it show the results between this date range in the month of 'April', 'January', 'February', 'March'.**

Please tell me and show me a way how I overcome and fix that problem

Comment: transform them in timestamp, easier to test

Comment: what is the data type of `col_date` in the table ?

Comment: How? by using strtotime, please describe me in describe me in details, I used several things but it can't compare the month

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty the datatype is varchar

Comment: Use a `DATE` column instead.

Comment: @AyanB Yes, strtotime() or use timestamp in your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing date as `varchar` or `TEXT` makes it difficult for comparison. So better to store as `date` or `datetime`.

In your case the workaround is

```
$backdate = date('Y-m-d', time());
$date1 = strtotime($backdate);
$date = strtotime("-7 day", $date1);
$prevdate = date('Y-m-d', $date);


select * from 
`requisition` 
WHERE 
date_format(str_to_date(col_date,'%m-%b-%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d') >= '$prevdate' 
AND date_format(str_to_date(col_date,'%m-%b-%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d') <= '$curdate'
order by `rq_no` DESC
```

So I am taking the input dates in Y-m-d format.
Then in the where clause used the mysql functions `date_format` and `str_to_date`.
str_to_date will convert the varchar date to real date followed by a format and use them in the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Try It:

```
$backdate = date('d-M-Y', time());
$date1 = strtotime($backdate);
$date = strtotime("-7 day", $date1);


select * from `requisition` WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(col_date) >= '$date' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(col_date) <= '$date1'  order by `rq_no` DESC
```